# Select control and DOM

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, dom

I am trying to create a JS function that will take a value from a dropdownlist, add it as a query string to a http link and then open that link.
How to go about that?

Let's say this is the `<select>`

```
<select>
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```

How would I use that in DOM to access the value of the selected item on the DDL?

```
function openlink(link) {
            window.open(link + "SELECTED_ITEM_GOES_HERE");
        }
```

What is the syntax for SELECTED_ITEM_GOES_HERE?

Comment: Do you require it onchange ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:
[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

And this:
[How to set querystring with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546207/how-to-set-querystring-with-javascript)

To produce this:

```
<select id="test">
   <option>Volvo</option>
   <option>Saab</option>
   <option>Mercedes</option>
   <option>Audi</option>
</select>

<script>
var ddl = document.getElementById('test');
ddl.onchange = function(){
    window.location = 'https://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=' + ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
};
</script>
```

Comment: hanks. that works but only for odd items on the list, so if the list has 1,2,3,4,5 it would only change when selecting 1,3 or 5. why is that

Comment: I did have to put the script above in another function and then call it with the "onchanged" in the `select` definition as having the script in the head and the select below causes an error due to order of loading