# Reload page on browser history back button

Tags: javascript, browser, location, back-button

I want the page to reload on hitting the browser history back button. However, since the URL gets changed often using JavaScript's `window.history.pushState` I do not want to reload the page every time the `location` changes. On default the browser just changes the URL without reloading the page on hitting the back button.

(By this I would like to use the browser history back button as some kind of "undo" function.)

Comment: Maybe HTML5 can help you, look that [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507091/replacestate-vs-pushstate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507091/replacestate-vs-pushstate

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, using `replaceState()` instead of `pushState()` kills the "undo" function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function HandleBackFunctionality(){
   //For IE
   if(window.event){
       //To check if its Back
       if(window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0){
          alert("Browser back button is clicked…");
       //Its Refresh
       } else {
          alert("Browser refresh button is clicked…");
       }
   }
   //Other browsers
   else {
       if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 1){
          alert("Browser refresh button is clicked…");
       }
       if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 2){
          alert("Browser back button is clicked…");
       }
   }
}
```

You need to call this method on `onbeforeunload` event.

```
<body onbeforeunload="HandleBackFunctionality()">
```

This method, however, does not work with keyboard controls.

Comment: Gives me a "ReferenceError: event is not defined" in the console in Firefox. In Chrome there is no error, but the back button still does no refresh.