# Replace URL in address bar with a subdomain withOUT redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain, subdomain

I have total control over my entire domain and its subdomains, and I want to replace the URL displayed in the address bar with a subdomain but **not** redirect the page.

For example, when I load `subdomain.mydomain.com?register` I want the address bar to **display** `register.mydomain.com` *without* redirecting.

**ALL pages *and subdomains* of `mydomain.com` already have `document.domain = 'mydomain.com';` as the *first* thing in the `$(window).load(function () {` code of its external `.js` file.**

I've tried `history.pushState("", "", '/');` to strip away anything after the `subdomain.mydomain.com` (which works), and I've been able to display something *after* the `/` (which also works), but I can't get the displayed subdomain to change *before* the `/`.

How do I do this?  Is it possible at all?  If so, does it rely on `document.domain`?  And if it does, am I executing `document.domain` properly??

Should I put

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 document.domain = 'mydomain.com';
 </script>
```

***by itself*** in the `<head>` of my HTML files, or will it work just fine being in the `$(window).load(function () {` code of its external `.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about domain/subdomain things, but I have a page where a user can click multiple items and depending on his/her input, a **URL** that is displayed in browser's address bar changes. There is how I do it without redirecting:

```
var newurl = window.location.protocol 
    + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname 
    + StrippedQueryString + '&H=' + Parameter;

if (history.replaceState) {
    window.history.replaceState({ path: newurl }, '', newurl);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up going with `pushState();` instead of `replaceState();` so that the back button would still work they way I needed it to.  But thank you very much!!  This would have done what I needed, but apparely not have allowed the back button to work properly.  Source: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17507140/3762525](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17507140/3762525)