# react router v4 navigate/reload the same route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Whether it's using `this.props.history.push` or `<Link to={}>` the component won't rerender if it's already at the same url.

Sometime in my container there will be logic that render different pieces, I don't want to use `window.location.reload()` to hard refresh the entire thing.

Comment: Try look into [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), maybe that's what you want instead of reloading the page

Comment: show your use case

Comment: When you want to update same page don't reload it to update it, update state to update view.

Comment: @EdwinHarly I know what is conditional rendering, but this question is about routing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and its working.

```
<Route path='/get-random-poll' exact>
        <Redirect
             to={{
                  pathname: 'polls',
                  state: {
                     randomPoll: true
                  }
             }}
       />
</Route>
```

I make a route `/get-random-poll` that has nothing but redirect to the `/polls`.
So when you are on `/polls`, router goes `/get-random-poll` and it redirects to `/polls`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState`. They should do the trick.

About the difference between them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507140/5709697

Comment: what is the different btw `this.props.history.push` vs `history.pushState`? My question is about react-router not browser API.